# Why doesn't a 20 degree rotation change the slopes of $y=x$ and $y=\frac{x}{2}$ by the same amount?

Tags: graphing-functions, intuition, rotations

It seems that if I rotate different lines (lying in the same quadrant) the same number of degrees they move different amounts (in terms of their slope). (where the rotation is such that all the lines do not enter a different quadrant)

Can someone give me intuition why this is?

My guess was that maybe it has something to do with the nature of a circle.

Comment: Because the slope the tangent of the angle, and the tangent function is nonlinear.

Comment: @MattSamuel That helps, thank you. but now I'm wondering why the tangent function is nonlinear.

Comment: Perhaps you should wonder why it *would be* linear!

Comment: @user Tongue in cheek, that seems more like a philosophy question to me. From my perspective, it is what it is. But perhaps someone has a more insightful answer than that.

Comment: A rotation can't add the same constant to every slope, because then it would never make a line vertical.

Comment: @RobertIsrael Well, it would make a line near vertical.... but I see what you mean. I guess also that if it added the same constant to every slope then a rotation of $\theta$ would span a smaller arc for steeper slopes, which wouldn't make sense...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just reposting Matt Samuel's comment as an answer:

The slope is the tangent of the angle. The tangent is a nonlinear function (so going from, for example, 5 to 25 degrees will yield a different change in slope from going from 10-30 degrees, even though the change in degrees is the same)

Answer (score 0):

Slope is $\tan x$ , $x$ being the angle the line makes with $x$ axis. $x$ is 45 in the line $y=x$ and around 26 when $2y=x$. As you know that $\tan$ approaches infinity when $x$ approaches 90, so as we add 20 to 45, the value of $\tan$ will increase at a greater rate than when we add 20 to ~26.

Comment: No, $\tan$ approaches $\infty$ at $\frac\pi2$ is not sufficient to prove the increase is greater. You need to prove $\tan''(x)>0$.

Comment: @Kemono Chen I was just trying to give the general idea with using only angles. For more rigorous proof, your approach is correct.